# Passing a callback function to another function

Tags: javascript, callback

Here is a simplified version of some javascript I'm working on:

```
function freshRooms (callWhenDone) {
var RoomRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
RoomRequest.open ("GET", "/myAjaxURL", true);
RoomRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (RoomRequest.readyState === 4 && RoomRequest.status === 200) {

        callWhenDone ();
    }
}
RoomRequest.send();
}

var woopy = 0;
function showwoop() {
    console.log("woopy=" + woopy++);
}

/* refresh - Called on a timer every four seconds */
function refresh () {
    freshRooms(showwoop);
}

TimerFunc = setInterval(refresh, 4000);
```

What I want is to be able to pass a function to freshRooms so when it receives a response to its ajax request, it will execute different functions appropriate to various different situations. In this example I'm just passing it a simple function that outputs a counter to the console.

When I execute this code in Chrome, I get "Type error: undefined is not a function" on the line that contains  `callWhenDone();`

But despite that error, Chrome then goes ahead and executes the function anyway, and I see the counter incrementing in the console every four seconds, as I would expect.

When I execute this code in Firefox, I get "callWhenDone is not a function", and then the function never executes.

I don't understand the problem. As I understand it, the anonymous function within freshRooms should know about all the variables defined by freshRooms.  Am I doing something inherently wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: replacing `/myAjaxURL` with `/`, and pasting your code into a chrome console prompt, I was able to get the expected behavior (woopy++ and printed every 4 seconds). In Firefox I get a malformed URI, which when fixed to point at something like google, gives me the expected behavior.

Comment: Is it possible that you call `freshRooms()` (without a callback) somewhere else as well?

Comment: Bergi, you nailed it. I had forgotten that elsewhere in this complex app there was another call to freshRooms that did not pass a parameter. Thanks (to all responders here)!

Answer (score 0):

Does this fiddle work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/napple/4GDQe/ (I just added a `document.write` alongside the `console.log`.) It works in both current version of FF and Chrome for me.

Is it possible that when you simplified the code you posted above, that the problem was eliminated? If so, we might need to see that actual code.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works, and yes, my simplification of the code eliminated the problem, which Bergi called my attention to. Thanks!